# Why can't I copy an array by using `=`?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm starting to learn C by reading K&R and going through some of the exercises.  After some struggling, I was finally able to complete exercise 1-19 with the code below:

```
/* reverse: reverse the character string s */
void reverse(char s[], int slen)
{
  char tmp[slen];
  int i, j;

  i = 0;
  j = slen - 2;    /* skip '\0' and \n */

  tmp[i] = s[j];
  while (i <= slen) {
    ++i;
    --j;
    tmp[i] = s[j];
  }

  /* code from copy function p 29 */
  i = 0;
  while ((s[i] = tmp[i]) != '\0')
    ++i;

}
```

My question is regarding that last bit of code where the `tmp` char array is copied to `s`.  Why doesn't a simple `s = tmp;` work instead?  Why does one have to iterate through the array copying index by index?

Comment: K&R did not use your solution - they wrote for C89, not C99, but your solution uses a VLA (variable-length array) which was only added in C99.  Additionally, there is no guarantee that there is a newline in the string - AFAIK.  And conventionally, the length of a string already excludes the terminal null.  That means your '-2' is probably incorrect.  The condition in the first while loop should use '<' instead of '<='; there is no virtue in swapping the central character with itself.  The fastest solution swaps the array in situ with no temporary array.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  

You're right, I was thinking about the -2 this morning since that was a hack I did last night at 3AM just to get it to work.  I probably should just put an if (s[i] != '\n' || s[i] != '\0') in the in the first while loop.

Comment: Old comment, but (s[i] != '\n' || s[i] != '\0') is always true.

Comment: There is no logical answer - it's totally possible to add such feature into the language - actually I'm currently using a modified gcc compiler which accepts arrays and structure assignments even with incompatible types (because who have time to write stupid casts).

Comment: You could even do something like `char arr[20] = *p;` since `*p` is an lvalue. The change took me like 5 mins to make - I only added a single `if`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Maybe I'm just old and grumpy, but the other answers I've seen seem to miss the point completely.

C does not do array assignments, period.  You cannot assign one array to another array by a simple assignment, unlike some other languages (PL/1, for instance; Pascal and many of its descendants too - Ada, Modula, Oberon, etc.).  Nor does C really have a string type.  It only has arrays of characters, and you can't copy arrays of characters (any more than you can copy arrays of any other type) without using a loop or a function call.  [String literals don't really count as a string type.]

The only time arrays are copied is when the array is embedded in a structure and you do a structure assignment.

In my copy of K&R 2nd Edition, exercise 1-19 asks for a function `reverse(s)`; in my copy of K&R 1st Edition, it was exercise 1-17 instead of 1-19, but the same question was asked.

Since pointers have not been covered at this stage, the solution should use indexes instead of pointers.  I believe that leads to:

```
#include <string.h>
void reverse(char s[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = strlen(s) - 1;
    while (i < j)
    {
        char c = s[i];
        s[i++] = s[j];
        s[j--] = c;
    }
}

#ifdef TEST
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char buffer[256];
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != 0)
    {
        int len = strlen(buffer);
        if (len == 0)
            break;
        buffer[len-1] = '\0';  /* Zap newline */
        printf("In:  <<%s>>\n", buffer);
        reverse(buffer);
        printf("Out: <<%s>>\n", buffer);
    }
    return(0);
}
#endif /* TEST */
```

Compile this with -DTEST to include the test program and without to have just the function `reverse()` defined.

With the function signature given in the question, you avoid calling `strlen()` twice per line of input.  Note the use of `fgets()` — even in test programs, it is a bad idea to use `gets()`.  The downside of `fgets()` compared to `gets()` is that `fgets()` does not remove the trailing newline where `gets()` does.  The upsides of `fgets()` are that you don't get array overflows and you can tell whether the program found a newline or whether it ran out of space (or data) before encountering a newline.

Answer (score 8):

Your `tmp` array was declared on [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation) and so when your method completes, the memory used to hold the values will be freed because of [scoping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(programming)).

`s = tmp` means that `s` should point to the same memory location as `tmp`. This means that when `tmp` is freed, `s` will still be pointing to a now possible invalid, freed memory location.

This type of error is referred to as a [dangling pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).

**Edit:** This isn't a dangling modifier as pointed out in the comments of this answer. The issue is that saying `s = tmp` only changes what the parameter points to, not what the actual array that was passed.

Also, you could perform your reverse with a single pass and without allocating a whole array in memory by just swapping the values in place one by one:

```
void reverse(char s[], int slen) {
    int i = 0;        // First char
    int j = slen - 2; // Last char minus \n\0
    char tmp = 0;     // Temp for the value being swapped

    // Iterate over the array from the start until the two indexes collide.
    while(i < j) {
        tmp = s[i];  // Save the eariler char
        s[i] = s[j]; // Replace it with the later char
        s[j] = tmp;  // Place the earlier char in the later char's spot
        i++;         // Move forwards with the early char
        j--;         // Move backwards with the later char
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 - because unlike the loads of other answers, you actually say tmp *is an array*, and *not* a pointer. The other answers would confuse me if i were him, thinking "huh, what pointer do they talk about?? tmp is an array!"

Comment: Won't speaking of tmp as an array would be like keeping him under confusion for longer. 
tmp is a pointer to an array, thats the correct definition. The sooner he learns, the better, isn't it?

Comment: !litb temp is definitely a pointer.  It's a pointer to the first character of the array.  Understanding how to write the [] operator as a macro would require you to full understand this.

Comment: There is no dangling pointer in his code, assigning tmp to s just modifies the local copy of the pointer to the array.  When the function returns, the original s pointer and the array are completely untouched.

Comment: Ah of course.  I had read about this the other day on a C++ thread.  Also thanks for the style/optimization advice!

Comment: Elitecoder, the definition is that it *is* an array (variadic length array). The definition of a pointer to an array (that array) would be char(*ptmp)[slen] = &tmp; I don't see why it would "keep him under confusion" if we speak of tmp as an array, because it *is* an array. sizeof(tmp) will give you slen. What isn't an array is s. The truth can be confusing, but that doesn't mean we should make appear it simplier by telling the wrong things - *that* will just confuse him! Start reading the Standard before you make fun of me, please

Comment: The -2 is wrong.  The strlen() function does not include the null in the count.  And there was nothing in the question (K&R 2nd Edn, Ex 1-19) about 'reverse a string except for the newline at the end'.

Comment: I'm not using the strlen() function since it hasn't been introduced yet in Ch. 1;  as far as what the exercise stated, I'm not really doing this to get the answer perfect (is there even an official list of answers?) but for practice.  For me, it wouldn't make sense to put a newline at the beginning of a line/string.

Comment: @llamaoo7: there is no variable temp. In the question, the variable tmp is an array; that is what 'char tmp[slen];' defines, and no weasel wording gets around it. It is an ARRAY - a variable length array, indeed, and those are a feature of C99, not C89. You are correct that when you pass tmp to a function, then it decays to a pointer to the first character, but it is not itself a pointer. A pointer, it would be declared 'char *tmp;'. You are setting yourself up for serious misunderstandings and a lifetime of misery if you don't realize the difference.

Answer (score 4):

Because both s and tmp are memory addressees. If you s = tmp, both pointers would point to the same array.

Suppose that we have

```
char s[] ="ab"; 

/*
* Only for explanatory purposes.
* 
*/
void foo(char s[]){ 
    char tmp [] = "cd";
    s= tmp;
 }

foo(s);
```

after s= tmp you would have

```
s[0] : 'c'
s[1] : 'd'
s[2] : '\0'
```

Even though both arrays have the same data, a change in  tmp, will affect both of them, because both arrays are actually the same. They both contain data that´s in the same memory address. So by changing any position of the tmp array, or destroying the tmp array, s would be affected in the same way.

By looping over the array, what you are doing is moving a piece of data from one memory address to another.

In my copy of K & R, pointers are explained in chapter 4. A quick glance through the first pages may be of help.

Comment: Ben S: Thanks for your feedback. I've re arranged my answer.

Comment: You cannot do the assignment s = tmp;
Arrays cannot be assigned in C. Pointers can though, but a pointer is not an array. (The name of an array gets promoted to a pointer to its first element when used as a value though, so if 's' were a pointer you'd be right.

Comment: I recommend this pet peeve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423823/whats-your-favorite-programmer-ignorance-pet-peeve/484900#484900

Comment: @litb: Now i know what pet peeve is :).

Comment: "s will point to a stack variable when foo ends, that will yield into undefined results."  That is not right.  Only foo's s variable ever points to "cd".  The caller's s is not modified.  It will still point to ab.   Try it!

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen: Thanks, you are right. This has been very educating.

Comment: @Tom, i added a new section to my pet peeve, explaining how "s" of foo is different from the global "s"

Answer (score 1):

To round out the discussion here are two other possible ways to reverse as string:

```
void reverse(char string1[], char string2[])
{
  int i = 0, len = 0;

  while(string2[len] != '\0')   // get the length of the string
      len++;

  while(len > 0)
  {
    string1[i] = string2[len-1]; // copy the elements in reverse
    i++;
    len--;
  }
  string1[i] = '\0'; // terminate the copied string 
}
```

Or recursively:

```
void reverse (const char *const sPtr)
{
  //if end of string
  if (sPtr[0] == '\0')
  {
    return;
  }
  else  //not end of the string...
   {
    reverse(&sPtr[1]);  //recursive step
    putchar(sPtr[0]);   //display character
   }
}
```

Comment: The second solution displays the string in reverse order without changing the string - whereas the exercise requests that the string is reversed without printing it.  The first solution would be better if it use strlen() and if the subscript '[len-1]' avoided the repeated subtraction (by decrementing len before starting the loop).

Answer (score 0):

because tmp is a pointer, and you need to get a copy, not a "link".

Comment: I recommend this pet peeve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423823/whats-your-favorite-programmer-ignorance-pet-peeve/484900#484900

Answer (score 0):

In case of s=tmp, the value of tmp which is the also the beginning address of the array, would get copied to s.

That way both s and tmp will point to the same address in memory, which I think is not the purpose.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

There's an interesting sub-thread in this thread about arrays and pointers
I found [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)#Arrays) on wikipedia with a peculiar code snippet showing just how 'plasticine' C can be!

```
/* x designates an array */
x[i] = 1;
*(x + i) = 1;
*(i + x) = 1;
i[x] = 1; /* strange, but correct: i[x] is equivalent to *(i + x) */
```

Of course what's even more confusing in C is that I can do this:

```
unsigned int someval = 0xDEADD00D;
char *p = (char *)&someval;

p[2] = (char)0xF0;
```

So the interchangibility of pointers and arrays seems so deep-set in the C language as to be almost intentional.
What does everyone else think?

---Original Post---
s and tmp are both pointers so doing s = tmp will simply make s point at the address where tmp lives in memory.
Another problem with what you outlined is that tmp is a local variable so will become 'undefined' when it goes out of scope i.e when the function returns.

Make sure you thoroughly grasp these three concepts and you won't go far wrong

1. Scope
2. The difference between the stack and the heap
3. Pointers

Hope that helps and keep going!

Answer (score 0):

Try experimenting and see what happens when you do things like this:

```
void modifyArrayValues(char x[], int len)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        x[i] = i;
}

void attemptModifyArray(char x[], int len)
{
    char y[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        y[i] = i;
    x = y;
}


int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    char x[10];
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        x[i] = 0;

    attemptModifyArray(x, 10);
    for (i=0; i < 10; ++i)
        printf("%d\n", x[i]); // x is still all 0's

    modifyArrayValues(x, 10);
    for (i=0; i < 10; ++i)
        printf("%d\n", x[i]); // now x has 0-9 in it
}
```

What happens when you modify the array directly in `attemptModifyArray`, you are just overwriting a local copy of the address of the array `x`.  When you return, the original address is still in `main`'s copy of x.

When you modify the values in the array in `modifyArrayValues`, you are modifying the actual array itself which has its address stored in `modifyArrayValues` local copy of `x`.  When you return, `x` is still holding on to the same array, but you have modified the values in that array.

Answer (score -2):

A very straight forward answer would be -
both s and tmp are pointers to a memory location and not the arrays themselves.
In other words, s and tmp are memory addresses where the array values are stored but not the values themselves.
And one of the common ways to access these array values are by using indices like s[0] or tmp[0].

Now, if you will try to simply copy, s = tmp, the memory address of tmp array will be copied over to s. This means that, the original s array will be lost and even s memory pointer will now point to tmp array.

You will understand these concepts well with due time so keep going through the book.
I hope this elementary explanation helps.

Comment: I recommend this pet peeve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423823/whats-your-favorite-programmer-ignorance-pet-peeve/484900#484900

Comment: -1: `tmp` is an array, not a pointer.  Arrays are not pointers, though they are closely related.  Unfortunately, only 10k users can see the information that is pointed to.